# Unable to execute dex & Conversion to Dalvik format failed

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I've seen this question being asked and answered a few times but it didn't work for me.
Eclipse is throwing:

```
[2013-03-16 17:45:34 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2013-03-16 17:45:34 - my-app-phone] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Some say that's a build path issue caused by having bin folder included in your build path.
Others say to increase the memory allocated in eclipse.ini to -Xms128m -Xmx512m or something higher, but this didn't do it for me either.

This is the only project throwing this error and it only happens with my Win 7 Pro at home. At work I've Mac OSX Mountain Lion and works fine.

[image: Android][image: Java Build Path Source][image: Java Build Path Libs][image: Java Build Path Source Order and Export]

What could it be?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While I was editing my screen shots I've found what could be causing this problem.

[image: Problem]

As you can seen I had two ***android-support-v4.jar***.
I've removed android-support-v4.jar, clean FacebookSDK project and my ***my-app-phone*** project launched correctly.

```
[2013-03-16 18:37:23 - my-app-phone] ------------------------------
[2013-03-16 18:37:23 - my-app-phone] Android Launch!
[2013-03-16 18:37:23 - my-app-phone] adb is running normally.
```

ps:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope it helps!
Take care ;)

Comment: You can't imagine how thankful I am for your answer! Wow this issue took me a week!

Comment: @Foo let me give you an advice: Forget Eclipse, use IntelliJ. The best IDE I've worked so far. You'll not regret ;)

Answer (score 6):

just Delete android-support-v4.jar from libs folder it solve

Answer (score 0):

I had an old version of Admob (which comes in a different file name: "GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.1.jar"
I removed it, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
In case of me, first i create the project that support android4.x.x, but then I have to support Android5.0.1.
The problem is project has both android-support-v4.jar and Android5.0.1/android.jar.
So When I delete android-support-v4.jar the problem solved.
Now I can test the project on my device.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to remove Android Private Libraries, see pic:

[image]